# Ignore width of inline element for a CSS / HTML / JS typing animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a typing animation which is centrally justified for the main page of my portfolio website. It works by animating the typing and deleting of the text using a javascript function and making a pipe '|' character at the end of the typed string blink using CSS keyframes.

[image]

My problem is that the '|' character (typing cursor) is accounted for when calculating the width of the line of text. This forces all preceding characters slightly to the left making the typing animation text off center.

Animation with cursor:

[image: Animation with cursor]

Animation without cursor:

[image: Animation without cursor]

Code:

```js
const cursorElement = document.getElementById('cursor');
const textElement = document.getElementById('typed-text');

const texts = ['Software Engineer', 'Programmer', 'Tech Geek', 'Coffee Lover', 'Pasta Connoisseur' ];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = '';
let letter = '';
let isDeleting = false;

(function type() {

  if(count === texts.length){
    count = 0;
  }
  currentText = texts[count];

  if(isDeleting) {
    letter = currentText.slice(0, index--);
  } else {
    letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);
  }

  textElement.textContent = letter;

  if(letter.length === currentText.length){
    isDeleting = true;
    setTimeout(type, 1000);
  } else if (isDeleting && index === -1) {
    isDeleting = false;
    count++;
    setTimeout(type, 500);
  } else {
    setTimeout(type, 100);
  }
}());
```

```css
@import"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@400;500;600&amp;family=Roboto:wght@400;500&ampdisplay=swap";

:root {
    --header-height: 3.5rem;
    --first-color: hsl(207, 65%, 65%);
    --title-color: hsl(207, 4%, 16%);
    --text-color: hsl(207, 4%, 28%);
    --text-color-light: hsl(207, 4%, 56%);
    --body-color: hsl(207, 4%, 99%);
    --container-color: hsl(207, 4%, 95%);
    --gradient-color: linear-gradient( 180deg, hsla(190, 48%, 72%, 0), rgb(137, 135, 154) );
    --body-font: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    --title-font: "Lora", serif;
    --biggest-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
    --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
    --h3-font-size: 1rem;
    --normal-font-size: .938rem;
    --small-font-size: .813rem;
    --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
    --tiny-font-size: .625rem;
    --font-medium: 500;
    --font-semi-bold: 600;
    --z-normal: 1;
    --z-tooltip: 10;
    --z-fixed: 100
}

* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    padding:0;
    margin:0
}

.main {
    overflow:hidden
}

.home__title {
    color:var(--title-color);
    font-family:var(--title-font);
    font-weight:var(--font-medium);
    text-align:center;
    font-size:var(--biggest-font-size);
    letter-spacing:.3px;
    margin-bottom:.5rem
}

.typing-effect {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*position: relative;*/
    
}

#cursor {
    animation: blink 1s infinite;
    padding-bottom: 0.05em;
    padding-left: 0.03em;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    white-space: pre;
}

@keyframes blink {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    50% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
    <main class="main">
      <section class="home section" id="home">
        <div class="home__container container grid section__border" id="maincard">
            <div class="home__data grid">
                <div id="home__title" class="home__title">Hello World, I'm Dan<br>
                    <div id="typing-div" class="typing-effect">
                        <span id="typed-text"></span>
                        <span id="cursor">|</span>
                      </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </section>
     </main>
```

How can I make it so that the cursor width is ignored when calculating the width of the typed text?

Comment: Making the cursor `position: absolute` will take it out of the flow and it won’t contribute to the width so it won’t affect the centering.

Comment: @ray this unfortunately breaks the animation since then the cursor does not follow the end of the text as it is being typed

Comment: It will if you position it accordingly, `right: 0` or whatever. (You’ll also have to make the container `position: relative` to establish a positioning context.)

Comment: I am not seeing a cursor at all when running the snippet - is something missing?

Comment: @AHaworth yes, just needed to add the '|' character in the <span id="cursor"></span> element. I've edited my post to add this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the cursor is just a visual clue it can be removed from the DOM.

This can be done by putting it instead into the after pseudo element of the text itself with position absolute. It then will not affect the width of the actual text.

```js
const cursorElement = document.getElementById('cursor');
const textElement = document.getElementById('typed-text');

const texts = ['Software Engineer', 'Programmer', 'Tech Geek', 'Coffee Lover', 'Pasta Connoisseur'];
let count = 0;
let index = 0;
let currentText = '';
let letter = '';
let isDeleting = false;

(function type() {

  if (count === texts.length) {
    count = 0;
  }
  currentText = texts[count];

  if (isDeleting) {
    letter = currentText.slice(0, index--);
  } else {
    letter = currentText.slice(0, ++index);
  }

  textElement.textContent = letter;

  if (letter.length === currentText.length) {
    isDeleting = true;
    setTimeout(type, 1000);
  } else if (isDeleting && index === -1) {
    isDeleting = false;
    count++;
    setTimeout(type, 5000);
  } else {
    setTimeout(type, 1000);
  }
}());
```

```css
@import"https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lora:wght@400;500;600&amp;family=Roboto:wght@400;500&ampdisplay=swap";
:root {
  --header-height: 3.5rem;
  --first-color: hsl(207, 65%, 65%);
  --title-color: hsl(207, 4%, 16%);
  --text-color: hsl(207, 4%, 28%);
  --text-color-light: hsl(207, 4%, 56%);
  --body-color: hsl(207, 4%, 99%);
  --container-color: hsl(207, 4%, 95%);
  --gradient-color: linear-gradient( 180deg, hsla(190, 48%, 72%, 0), rgb(137, 135, 154));
  --body-font: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  --title-font: "Lora", serif;
  --biggest-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h1-font-size: 1.5rem;
  --h2-font-size: 1.25rem;
  --h3-font-size: 1rem;
  --normal-font-size: .938rem;
  --small-font-size: .813rem;
  --smaller-font-size: .75rem;
  --tiny-font-size: .625rem;
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  --z-normal: 1;
  --z-tooltip: 10;
  --z-fixed: 100
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}

.main {
  overflow: hidden
}

.home__title {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-family: var(--title-font);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: var(--biggest-font-size);
  letter-spacing: .3px;
  margin-bottom: .5rem
}

.typing-effect {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /*position: relative;*/
}

#typed-text {
  position: relative;
}

#typed-text::after {
  content: '|';
  position: absolute;
  animation: blink 1s infinite;
  padding-bottom: 0.05em;
  padding-left: 0.03em;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  white-space: pre;
}

@keyframes blink {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main">
  <section class="home section" id="home">
    <div class="home__container container grid section__border" id="maincard">
      <div class="home__data grid">
        <div id="home__title" class="home__title">Hello World, I'm Dan<br>
          <div id="typing-div" class="typing-effect">
            <span id="typed-text"></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
</main>
```